# msvc std::function doesn't accept generic lambda with a nested lambda

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, lambda, c++17

The following works with gcc 5.2 and clang 3.7 but fails with msvc 2015:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  auto const foo = [](auto&& i) {
    auto const bar = []{ return 100; };
    return bar();
  };

  std::function<int(int)> fn = foo;
  return 0;
}
```

Is it a bug in msvc or are gcc and clang too lax?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: It compiles if you change it to `auto const foo = [](auto&& i) -> int { `

Comment: @melak47 explicitly specifying the return type confirmed working with vs2015. Although it doesn't work with the latest (is it the latest?) compiler v19.00.23602.0 (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). Anyhow I think it shouldn't be necessary to specify the return type.

Comment: I'd definitely still file a bug, both Update 1 and what I presume is the WIP Update 2 build of the compiler don't accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If I try this using [Microsoft's official online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), which is version 19.00.23602.0(x86) last updated Dec 3, 2015, I get execution timed out<sup>1</sup>. Removing `std::function<int(int)> fn = foo;` will allow successful compilation. Feel free to let Microsoft know via [Visual Studio Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) so they can investigate the bug and report it. Yes, one can waste time flipping through the standard to see if this is "legal" code, but you'll get much more bang for your buck by using the bug tracker.

<sup>1</sup> An internal compiler error is *always* a bug.

Comment: I didn't know ms provides an online compiler. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is [a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1557383/nested-generic-lambdas-fails-to-compile-c) in Visual C++ 2015, but it seems to have been fixed as of Update 3. The workaround is to specify the return type of the outer lambda (thanks to [melak47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248067/msvc-stdfunction-doesnt-accept-generic-lambda-with-a-nested-lambda#comment56238075_34248067)).

This fails:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<void (bool)> f =
        [](auto&&)
        {
            []{};
        };
}
```

with:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

a.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\type_traits(1348):
    error C2065: '_Args': undeclared identifier
    [...and more]
```

But this works:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<void (bool)> f =
        [](auto&&) -> void
        {
            []{};
        };
}
```